# How to append custom text to the output of 'categories widget'?

Tags: customization, filters, widgets, hooks, sidebar

How do I customize the "categories widget" to append additional text on the sidebar display?

from

```
category 1
category 2
category 3
category 4
```

to

```
category 1 folder
category 2 folder
category 3 folder
category 4 folder
```

Without actually modifying the category name in the database, I would like to add some actual customized text to the sidebar front-end display.

Currently my sidebar is being called via `dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' )`

**Update:**

I managed to use a plugin to solve my problem.

[Widget Output Filters](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-output-filters/)

Is there any recommendation of how to get this done without the use of a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append text to the end of the titles in that widget and nothing more i.e. does not matter the URL, you can just use some CSS.

```
<li>
 <a class="my-folder-categories">Category 1</a>
</li>

a.my-folder-categories-folder:after {content:" folder";
```

This will effectivly make the text appear as so:

```
category 1 folder
```

Be sure to add that space in the content value.

If you want to use the plugin mentioned but not as a plugin, use the source and modify to your specs.

```
/**
* Class Widget_Output_Filters
*
* Allows developers to filter the output of any WordPress widget.
*/
class Widget_Output_Filters {

/**
* Initializes the functionality by registering actions and filters.
*/
public function __construct() {

// Priority of 9 to run before the Widget Logic plugin.
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', array( $this, 'filter_dynamic_sidebar_params' ), 9 );
}

/**
* Replaces the widget's display callback with the Dynamic Sidebar Params display callback, storing the original callback for use later.
*
* The $sidebar_params variable is not modified; it is only used to get the current widget's ID.
*
* @param array $sidebar_params The sidebar parameters.
*
* @return array The sidebar parameters
*/
public function filter_dynamic_sidebar_params( $sidebar_params ) {

if ( is_admin() ) {
return $sidebar_params;
}

global $wp_registered_widgets;
$current_widget_id = $sidebar_params[0]['widget_id'];

$wp_registered_widgets[ $current_widget_id ]['original_callback'] = $wp_registered_widgets[ $current_widget_id ]['callback'];
$wp_registered_widgets[ $current_widget_id ]['callback'] = array( $this, 'display_widget' );

return $sidebar_params;
}

/**
* Execute the widget's original callback function, filtering its output.
*/
public function display_widget() {

global $wp_registered_widgets;
$original_callback_params = func_get_args();

$widget_id         = $original_callback_params[0]['widget_id'];
$original_callback = $wp_registered_widgets[ $widget_id ]['original_callback'];

$widget_id_base = $original_callback[0]->id_base;
$sidebar_id     = $original_callback_params[0]['id'];

if ( is_callable( $original_callback ) ) {

ob_start();
call_user_func_array( $original_callback, $original_callback_params );
$widget_output = ob_get_clean();

/**
* Filter the widget's output.
*
* @param string $widget_output  The widget's output.
* @param string $widget_id_base The widget's base ID.
* @param string $widget_id      The widget's full ID.
* @param string $sidebar_id     The current sidebar ID.
*/
echo apply_filters( 'widget_output', $widget_output, $widget_id_base, $widget_id, $sidebar_id );
}
}
}
```

Comment: It does the trick.  Do you know if it is search engine friendly and will this css solution be indexable by Google?

Comment: Good question, @KDX. It is not considered by search engines as it is just a CSS property. Depending on your base keywords and page by page structure I don't see how this would inhibit your serps. *it would not affect the links otherwise.

Comment: The other easy solution is to just rename the categories to include "folder."

Comment: I do plan to add keyword instead of just "folder" to the category links.  Your solution is convenient and I can easily append text, but it won't serve my actual needs.  And yes, I thought of that,  renaming is an easy solution, however, I'm trying to append various keywords to the same category across different pages/locations, thus I would like to keep the category short so I can work with it.  Currently I'm using `str_replace()` to apply text inject from `get_the_category_list()`, only `widget` part is giving me a hard time.

Comment: So you're doing a str_replace() within the WP function to find categories and append or change the title?

Comment: Yes, I'm using this method to alter titles of categories for the occurrences across post pages.  But when it comes to sidebar widget, I don't know how to extract the titles and make further manipulation.  Using the plugin mentioned in my question can help me use the similar approach with `str_replace()`.  Basically I made the text append by replacing `</a>` with `anything</a>`. But I would prefer a solution without depending on 3rd party plugins.

Comment: I see. Well if the plugin is useful but you don't want it as a plugin then just write it into your existing code i.e. functions.php - I'll post the code above..